# Rails include a select tag inside a form_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `form_with`

```
<%= form_with(model: @account, url: account_path(@account), local: true) do |form| %>
```

And I want to include the following `select_tag`.?

```
<%= label_tag "authy-countries", "Country code:" %>
<%= select_tag "authy-countries", nil, name: 'country_code', 'data-show-as': 'number' %>
```

I need these two in order to load the content of the select_tag:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/authy-form-helpers/2.3/form.authy.min.css', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/authy-form-helpers/2.3/form.authy.min.js', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Hey @Dev, couple of question: What happens when you currently do it? What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: Hey @SRack, thanks for the reply again! When I submit the form... the country_code does not get submitted. I can't see it in the rails console. I found this with does get submitted`<%= form.text_field "country_code", :id => "authy-countries", 'data-show-as': 'number' %>` but if I restart the server it doesn't appear correctly... something to do with this I guess `data-show-as': 'number'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= form.label :”authy-countries”, "Country code:" %>
<%= select :"authy-countries", [], name: 'country_code', 'data-show-as': 'number' %>
```

You should be able to use the standard [form select helper](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#select-boxes-for-dealing-with-models). The initial options set may need to be an empty array rather than nil, but try both.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @TomDunning, unfortunately the select filed doesn't show up correctly. It's suppose to show the country area codes but instead its just showing two values `name` & `data-show-as`. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: I take it the `data-show-as` tag is hooking some JS to populate the countries? Can I see the JS? Then I can get it working and update my answer